# Weird Java Behavior in CodingBat (Java Logic-2 MakeChocolate)

Tags: java

When I use the following code for MakeChocolate, it passes all tests about 50% of the time, and fails the last 4 sets with a Timeout error about 50% of the time. Could anyone explain why it seems to work some of the time but not other times? (I literally change nothing in between trials, I just press the "Go" button and it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.)

Perhaps it's a connection error or something? If anything, could one of you guys try it out on your browser and see if it's reproducible?

```
public int makeChocolate(int small, int big, int goal) {
  if ((goal - big*5) <= small && (goal %5) <= small) {
    int counter = 0;
    List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList();

    while(counter - big <= 0) {
       if ((goal - counter*5) >= 0) {
       myList.add(goal - counter*5);
       }
       counter += 1;
     }
    return myList.get(myList.size() - 1);
   }

  else {
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no problem in either Java, or CodingBat or network speed. This simply means the code you wrote completes all the tests 'just in time' when it does so and also 'just fails' to do so when it doesn't. To confirm I tested with various codes and found out the last fours tests fail for some codes because the code is simply not that efficient. for example the first code i used(a very simple snippet):-

```
public int makeChocolate(int small, int big, int goal) {
  int ans= -1;


  for(int i = 1; i <= small; i++){
  if(i + (big * 5) == goal){
  ans = i;
  }

  }return ans;
}
```

Obviously this code did not pass all the tests, but due to its low complexity it was able to pass those last four tests. Other code i used is :-

```
 public int makeChocolate(int small, int big, int goal) {
  int ans= -1;

 for(int j = 1; j <= big; j++){
 if(j * 5 < goal){
  for(int i = 1; i <= small; i++){
  if(i + (j * 5) == goal){
  ans = i;
  }}}
  else if(j * 5 == goal){
  ans = 0;}
  else{ for(int i = 1; i <= small; i++){
  if(i== goal){
  ans = i;}}}}return ans;
}
```

This code was able to pass all the above tests but was unable to pass in the codingbat required time limit, last four tests. The test it is not being able to pass in time according to me is the one where the values exceed thousand. You would have to change your code to be just a little bit more efficient if you are getting it in time 50% of the time. Good luck.